# VB Split Multiple Spaces and Remove Words

Tags: text, split

I'm making a little program so I can get a better view of donations for a game.
What I want the program to do is split the text from textbox1.text into multiple textboxes.

Example: I want to split this text `"20:12 01-04-2014   Ramon   Geen    $4.500.000.000"`.

So I want the name `"Ramon"` in a textbox called `Name1` and I want the money in a textbox called `Donation`.

I already know how to remove the date from the text but I don't know how to remove the comment which can be different than Geen and I also don't know how to split the name and donation into separate textboxes. Can anyone tell me how to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string is going to be completely variable then you may have some issues.

However, you know the following.

The right most text is always the money, so you can split the string on space and then put it into an array. Then the last element in the array will be the money. Also, the first portion will be the date. The second item in the array will be the name and everything else will be the comment.

I'm not going to code it all out for you, but if you have any questions just post the code and ill take a look.

Comment: Hey i have figured out how to remove the spaces but some spaces dont get remove. i tried to REmove the spaces from this string 17:19 03-04-2014  Incendico extra $2.000.000.000 but it doesnt work

Comment: Replace(TestString, " ", "")

Just use replace and replace the spaces for an empty quote set.

Comment: But there are no Spaces anymore it will say: Time : Date : NAme comment and Donation Because there are invisible characters. because i copied the donation line from an website and the dat is in 1 collum and the comment and stuff to